# How to count appearances (row-wise) of an element in multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I think this must certainly be a question that has been previously answered here, but I just can't word it right to find it so I'll give it a shot.

I have a data frame like this one:

```
player_id .... tag_0 tag_1 tag_2 tag_3 tag_4 tag_5
100       .... 1801   101   100   NA    NA    NA
...
100       .... 101     NA    NA   NA    NA    NA
```

I want to count the number of goals (tag 101) player 100 scored in a season. Thing is tags follow no order and are spread along 6 different columns. I thought of two solutions:

1. Counting the appearance of tag 101 in the 6 columns and adding the 6 values.
2. Merging the tag values into a single column as a list and then exploding the column. But there are two problems with this approach (I loose information on other descriptive tags for things more complicated than goals and I multiply the height of my data frame by 6 (it already has more than 500k observations per competition on average and I have 6 competitions, so that would be around 500k*36 observations to process)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume if any of the tags equal 101, it means the player has scored:

```py
df["goal_scored"] = df.loc[:, "tag_0":"tag_5"].eq(101).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly it! Really appreciate it